# catching all validation errors with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, mongoid, rescue

I tried doing this to catch all validation errors from a base class:

```
rescue_from Mongoid::Errors::Validations, :with => :rescue_from_validations
```

doesn't seem to work.

Also tried this:

```
around_filter :handle_errors
```

Neither works.

The sample scenario is i'm using devise and tried to create a user with a password less than 6 so i get a validation error:

["Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]

Is there anyway to catch this on a controller-wide level? Basically I want to write a single code to catch all validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to create your own `RegistrationsController` that inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController` (see [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) for more info), then you can add your `rescue_from` code in that controller.